# django autocomplete_light object has no attribute 'get_absolute_url' error

Tags: django, url, autocomplete

I am trying to implement a search box that has autocompletion and am using the autocomplete_light library. I have a class

```
class GenAutocomplete2(autocomplete_light.AutocompleteGeneric):
   choices = (
      Person.objects.all(),
      Other.objects.all()
   )
   search_fields = (
      ('first_name', 'last_name'),
      ('name',)
   )
```

that should allow me to search by first_name or last_name for Person objects, and just by name for Other objects. I register this autocomplete like this:

```
  autocomplete_light.register(GenAutocomplete2)
```

and display it in a template file as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Testing</title>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   {% include 'autocomplete_light/static.html' %}
</head>
<body>
   <h1> Search Page </h1>

   <form action="" method="post">

      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form }}
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

using a view

```
   form = MyForm()
   return render(request, 'test_html.html', {'form': form})
```

But, I get an error 'GenAutocomplete2' object has no attribute 'get_absolute_url'
and when I go to `http://localhost:8000/autocomplete/`, I see the following: [image: error]

where there is no autocomplete url for GenAutocomplete2